# Cannot send email on Ubuntu 14.10, Postfix and Dovecot

Tags: server, email, 14.10, postfix, dovecot

I am having trouble setting up my Ubuntu server installation to send/receive emails. I am fairly new to all of this so I apologise if I have not provided enough/correct information. Please do let me know if you need anything else. I am stuck as what to do next.

I have set up the server correctly and I have SSH'd into it.

---

When I try and send an email from the command line using:

```
mmail test@example.com
Cc: test@gmail.com
Subject: Test
This is a test
```

I get the following in my **/var/log/mail.log**

```
Nov 29 23:13:44 mikeserver postfix/pickup[24226]: 0A60F63E007E: uid=1000 from=<mike@mikeserver>
Nov 29 23:13:44 mikeserver postfix/cleanup[26218]: 0A60F63E007E: message-id=<20141129231344.0A60F63E007E@mikeserver>
Nov 29 23:13:44 mikeserver postfix/qmgr[24227]: 0A60F63E007E: from=<mike@mikeserver>, size=381, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Nov 29 23:13:45 mikeserver postfix/smtp[25920]: 0A60F63E007E: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.67.27]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.08/0/1.3/0.46, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1417302826 q5si38702680wia.0 - gsmtp)
Nov 29 23:13:48 mikeserver postfix/smtp[26219]: 0A60F63E007E: to=<test@example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[111.222.333.444]:25, delay=4.9, delays=0.08/0.01/4.3/0.5, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.exampleid: 550-Verification failed for <mike@mikeserver> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail to mike@mikeserver.  The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 29 23:13:49 mikeserver postfix/cleanup[26218]: 46C4163E007F: message-id=<20141129231349.46C4163E007F@mikeserver>
Nov 29 23:13:49 mikeserver postfix/bounce[26225]: 0A60F63E007E: sender non-delivery notification: 46C4163E007F
Nov 29 23:13:49 mikeserver postfix/qmgr[24227]: 46C4163E007F: from=<>, size=2631, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 29 23:13:49 mikeserver postfix/qmgr[24227]: 0A60F63E007E: removed
Nov 29 23:13:49 mikeserver postfix/local[26226]: 46C4163E007F: to=<mike@mikeserver>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.08/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Nov 29 23:13:49 mikeserver postfix/qmgr[24227]: 46C4163E007F: removed
```

---

I also get this message on my **OS X Mac Mail client**

```
This is the mail system at host mikeserver.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                  The mail system

<test@example.com>: host mail.example.com[111.222.333.444] said:
   550-Verification failed for <mike@mikeserver> 550-The mail server could not
   deliver mail to mike@mikeserver.  The account or domain may not exist, they
   may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify
   failed (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; mikeserver
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 8038563E007C
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; mike@mikeserver
Arrival-Date: Sat, 29 Nov 2014 22:47:58 +0000 (GMT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; mike@michaelnorris.co.uk
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.example.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-Verification failed for <mike@mikeserver> 550-The
   mail server could not deliver mail to mike@mikeserver.  The account or
   domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns
   entries. 550 Sender verify failed
```

---

When I try and send email from the server to any address I get the following returned message

```
Transcript of session follows.

Out: 220 mikeserver ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
In:  EHLO [192.168.0.12]
Out: 250-mikeserver
Out: 250-PIPELINING
Out: 250-SIZE 10240000
Out: 250-VRFY
Out: 250-ETRN
Out: 250-STARTTLS
Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Out: 250-8BITMIME
Out: 250 DSN
In:  STARTTLS
Out: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
In:  EHLO [192.168.0.12]
Out: 250-mikeserver
Out: 250-PIPELINING
Out: 250-SIZE 10240000
Out: 250-VRFY
Out: 250-ETRN
Out: 250-AUTH PLAIN
Out: 250-AUTH=PLAIN
Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Out: 250-8BITMIME
Out: 250 DSN
In:  AUTH PLAIN bWlrZQBtaWtlAHBhc3N3b3Jk
Out: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
In:  MAIL FROM:<mike@mikeserver>
Out: 250 2.1.0 Ok
In:  RCPT TO:<test@example.com>
Out: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error
In:  RCPT TO:<test@gmail.com>
Out: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error
In:  QUIT
Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

However OS X Mac Mail Connection Doctor can connect to the server's IMAP and SMTP just fine

[image: OS X Mac Mail Connection Doctor]

Running `lab_release -a` from OS X Terminal gives the following.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

---

Any information is greatly appreciated. I have been at this for hours. Even if it is just to get me to provide more information. I don't know where to look next.

Comment: What exactly is YOUR email address you are sending the email FROM? Have you purchased a domain to use for your email address? Also, have you port-forwarded the proper ports used in email communication? Sometimes the basics are actually the problems in the end. I can't tell you how many times something such as port-forwarding has fixed things for me.

Comment: try swaks, the swiss army knife for (something, smtp?).  It's great for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending mail originating from mike@mikeserver to an external domain. This domain checks if the address which is sending the mail from exists (anti-spam policy). mike@mikeserver is not an existing name on the internet so the message is bounced (sender verification failed).

just adjust you sending address to a domain which exists might help you in this case. However lots of servers also check your reverse dns to match you HELO/EHLO, so you identification should be made the same as your reverse dns for most domains to be able to send mail to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send from mikeserver, but that is not a fqdn.i assume mikeserver is your home machine on a dial up connection? You should use a mail relay to send mails from your home machine. If it is a server with a static ip you must check the dns name resolution is working forward and backward, your mx record is set correctly (mikeserver.yourdomain.tld) and the mailname of your server is set accordingly. You also should have a valid spf record for your server.

Comment: mikeserver is a separate box to my MacBook Pro. I have reserved the local IP address through my router/modem and I have a noip.me address pointing to it and server.mydomainname.com redirecting to the noip.me URL so it is a bit more personal. I guess I would be wrong in thinking that I can change the MX records for server.mydomainname.com?